# Hangman drawing regardless of correct letters (Python, turtle)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm creating a hangman game in Python 3.5.1 and everything is going well except for when it comes to the guessing part. I print "Hurray" when the letter is guessed correctly and I have it draw an additional body part when it is not guessed correctly. My problem is that even when a letter is guessed correctly it will also draw another body part:

```
import drawHangman
import turtle
import random

def main():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.setup(400, 400, 200, 200)
    HG = turtle.Turtle()  
    drawHangman.default(HG)

    wrongGuess = 0 
    maxGuesses = 0

    lines = open('wordlist.txt').read().splitlines()
    myline =random.choice(lines)
    print(myline)

    name = input("Welcome to hangman! What is your name? \n")
    print("Welcome", name + "! \n The rules are as follows: \n 1) No looking at answer list! \n 2) Do not have fun!! \n 3) No hacking my game!")
    tos = input("Do you accept the rules provided above? Type Yes or No. \n")

    if tos == "no": 
        print("Who cares! The rules suck anyways!")
    elif tos == "yes": 
        print("HI")
    else:
        print("You don't listen very well. I guess proceed ugh")

    while maxGuesses < 6:
        guess = input("Please input your guess!")
        maxGuesses += 1
        for char in myline:
            if char in guess:
                print("Hurray")
        else:
            wrongGuess += 1
            print("You have", 6 - maxGuesses, "guesses left!")

        if wrongGuess == 1:
            drawHangman.drawHead(HG)
        elif wrongGuess == 2:
            drawHangman.drawBody(HG) 
        elif wrongGuess == 3:
            drawHangman.drawLeftArm(HG)
        elif wrongGuess == 4:
            drawHangman.drawRightArm(HG)
        elif wrongGuess == 5:
            drawHangman.drawLeftLeg(HG)
        elif wrongGuess == 6:
            drawHangman.drawRightLeg(HG)

    else: 
        playAgain = input('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
        if playAgain == "yes":
            drawHangman.reset(HG)
            main()
        else:
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            return

main()
```

I know it has something to do with the part where else tells it there is a wrong letter but I can't figure it out. I've tried indenting it one more space, but that just prints the amount of guesses left. Any help is appreciated.

PS. The `drawHangman.*` routines come from a file I have in my src folder that contains body parts.

Answer (score 0):

You have indented the `else` clause (and the following lines) incorrectly - it's in the scope of the `for` loop instead of the `if` statement:

```
    for char in myline:
        if char in guess:
            print("Hurray")
        else:
            wrongGuess += 1
            print("You have", 6 - maxGuesses, "guesses left!")

        if wrongGuess == 1:
            drawHangman.drawHead(HG)
        # etc.
```

As you wrote it, the `else` clause and all the drawings are executed only after the entire `for` loop has finished.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7uTKA1b.png
http://i.imgur.com/TGdiX3I.png

I tried that, but I get weird results.

Comment: I can't quite match the output in your second screenshot to the part of the code shown in the source pane. Your program does have more problems. For example why are you iterating over all the characters in the user's input? Shouldn't only the first character be looked at? Every input will have at least a newline character that will not match any of the letters in your test word. It's still unclear to me how that message would be printed three times.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem raised in your question, there seem to be other issues with your code: your logic assumes/hardcodes 6 letter words; you're repeat game logic is actually recursive; you don't close the words file after you're finished with it; your yes/no question handling isn't robust; you repeat things, by recalling `main()`, that need only be done once; you don't display the current correct/unknown letter status.

Below is a rework of your code to address these issues and play an actual game of hangman:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random
import drawHangman

BODY_PARTS = [ \
    drawHangman.drawHead, drawHangman.drawBody, drawHangman.drawLeftArm, \
    drawHangman.drawRightArm, drawHangman.drawLeftLeg, drawHangman.drawRightLeg, \
    ]

MAXIMUM_WRONG_GUESSES = len(BODY_PARTS)

def hangman(HG):
    drawHangman.default(HG)

    with open('wordlist.txt') as file:
        lines = file.read().splitlines()

    word = random.choice(lines)
    letters = set(word)
    wrongGuesses = 0

    while letters and wrongGuesses < MAXIMUM_WRONG_GUESSES:

        for letter in word:
            print("*" if letter in letters else letter, end="")
        print(".")

        letter = input("Please input your guess: ")

        if letter in letters:
            print("Hurray!")
            letters.remove(letter)
        else:
            BODY_PARTS[wrongGuesses](HG)
            wrongGuesses += 1
            print("You have", MAXIMUM_WRONG_GUESSES - wrongGuesses, "guesses left!")

def main():
    screen = Screen()
    screen.setup(400, 400, 200, 200)

    turtle = Turtle()
    playAgain = True

    print("Welcome to hangman!")
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    print("Welcome", name + "!")
    print("The rules are as follows:")
    print(" 1) No looking at answer list!")
    print(" 2) Do not have fun!!")
    print(" 3) No hacking my game!")

    tos = input("Do you accept the rules provided above? (yes or no): ")

    if tos.lower().startswith("n"):
        print("Who cares! The rules suck anyways!")
    elif tos.lower().startswith("y"):
        print("Hi")
    else:
        print("You don't listen very well. I guess proceed ugh")

    while playAgain:
        hangman(turtle)

        answer = input('Do you want to play again? (yes or no): ')
        playAgain = answer.lower().startswith("y")

        if playAgain:
            drawHangman.reset(turtle)
        else:
            print("Thanks for playing!")

main()
```